# Query taking too long

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, query-optimization

I'm working on PostgreSQL (latest version), in a simple SCADA system. The problem is that every query involving the largest table in my schema [figure 1] takes about 2 hours.

[image: Schema]

What I want is to obtain the constructora's PKs for buildings (`edificio`) whose departments (`departamento`) record (`valor` in table `medicion`) surpluses in the measurement of "gas" or "electricidad" in 2010. So...

- `variable` contains the max value for a record (`valmax`)
- `medicion` contains the value of the metric (`valor`)

### Tables' Size (in rows).

- `constructura -> 10`
- `edificio -> 100`
- `departamento -> 50.000`
- `variable -> 8`
- `medicion_departamento -> 400.000`
- `medicion -> 8.000.000`

### Query

I've made a query with `INNER JOINs` that goes from the littlest tables (`constructora` and `variable`) to the biggest one (`medicion`).

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.id_constructora FROM
constructora C
INNER JOIN variable V ON (V.nombre = 'electricidad' OR V.nombre = 'gas')
INNER JOIN edificio E ON (E.id_constructora = C.id_constructora)
INNER JOIN departamento D ON (E.id_edificio = D.id_edificio)
INNER JOIN medicion M ON (M.id_variable = V.id_variable)
WHERE (
    (M.valor > V.valmax) AND
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.fecha) = 2010
);
```

### EXPLAIN

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=2343438.58..2343438.68 rows=10 width=4)"
"  Group Key: c.id_constructora"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=164536.25..1947605.25 rows=158333333 width=4)"
"        Hash Cond: (e.id_constructora = c.id_constructora)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=4.25..1510.75 rows=50000 width=4)"
"              Hash Cond: (d.id_edificio = e.id_edificio)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on departamento d  (cost=0.00..819.00 rows=50000 width=4)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=3.00..3.00 rows=100 width=8)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on edificio e  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=100 width=8)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=164136.12..164136.12 rows=31670 width=4)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..164136.12 rows=31670 width=4)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..163739.12 rows=3167 width=0)"
"                          Join Filter: ((m.valor > v.valmax) AND (v.id_variable = m.id_variable))"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on medicion m  (cost=0.00..162408.00 rows=38000 width=8)"
"                                Filter: (date_part('year'::text, fecha) = '2010'::double precision)"
"                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.13 rows=2 width=24)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on variable v  (cost=0.00..1.12 rows=2 width=24)"
"                                      Filter: (((nombre)::text = 'electricidad'::text) OR ((nombre)::text = 'gas'::text))"
"                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=10 width=4)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on constructora c  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=10 width=4)"
```

My question is what can I do to reduce -significantly- the execution time of my query?

Comment: How is the tables `variable` and `medicion` linked with other tables in the query? It seems that you have missed `medicion_departamento` in it...

Comment: But I only need "valmax" and not the data from medicion_departamento, because I know that medicion contains id_variable from medicion_departamento and that table got this value from variable

Comment: But you should at least to link `medicion` with `departamento` using `id_departamento` column. Isn't it?

Comment: This solved my problem! Now I'm getting the results in 3.2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems (according to the schema) your query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.id_constructora FROM
constructora C
  INNER JOIN edificio E ON (E.id_constructora = C.id_constructora)
  INNER JOIN departamento D ON (E.id_edificio = D.id_edificio)
  -- Changes here
  INNER JOIN medicion M ON (D.id_departamento = M.id_departamento)
  INNER JOIN variable V ON (M.id_variable = V.id_variable AND (V.nombre = 'electricidad' OR V.nombre = 'gas'))
WHERE (
    (M.valor > V.valmax) AND
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.fecha) = 2010
);
```

Because in your original query you have the cross join of `medicion` and `variable` tables with all other tables.

Also you should to have the functional index like

```
create index idx_medicion_fecha_year on medicion(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.fecha));
```

to be used for `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fecha) = 2010` condition.

Answer (score 1):

The `or` in the `join` is a performance killer.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.id_constructora
FROM constructora C INNER JOIN
     edificio E
     ON E.id_constructora = C.id_constructora INNER JOIN
     departamento D
     ON E.id_edificio = D.id_edificio LEFT JOIN
     variable ve
     ON ve.nombre = 'electricidad' AND M.valor > ve.valmax LEFT JOIN
     variable vg
     ON vg.nombre = 'gas' LEFT JOIN
     medicion me
     ON me.id_variable = ve.id_variable AND
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM me.fecha) = 2010 AND
         me.valor > ve.valmax LEFT JOIN
     medicion mg
     ON mg.id_variable = vg.id_variable AND
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM mg.fecha) = 2010 AND
        mg.valor > vg.valmax
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.fecha) = 2010 AND
      (me.id_variable IS NOT NULL OR mg.id_variable IS NOT NULL);
```

I also suspect that you want join conditions on `mg.id_departamento = d.id_departamento` and `me.id_departamento = d.id_departamento` in the appropriate `on` clauses.

This assumes that you have appropriate indexes on the join keys (particularly the primary keys).  In addition, you want an index on `variable(nombre, valor)` and `medicion(id_variable, fecha, valor)`.  If you are using `id_departamento`, it should be the first key in the index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem here is: what is V.id_variable?

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez . . . I misunderstood the data model.  I modified the answer.